# How can i display info?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I have this

```
angular.module('listController',[])
  .controller('listCtrl', function($scope, $http){
      $scope.loading = true;
      $http.get('/api/list').then(function(data){
        user = data.data.users;
        console.log(user);
      }), function(error){
        console.log(error);
      }
  })
```

This give me all the users that i have on my db, the problem is that i can't display the info on screen, how can i do it, maybe with ng-repeat but i dont know how can i do it, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use $scope.user instead of user.
2. use {{user}} in template

check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/luolisave/L8b9qLfc/2/